# box-shadow in opera (older) doesn't work as expected in one place

Tags: css, cross-browser, opera

I'm trying to make spacer with shadow and encountered weird problem. It looks differently in older opera and opera next (new opera) and other browsers
Older opera:
[image]

New opera (and other browsers):
[image]

Css code:

```
.spacer {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.mask {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 20px;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

 .mask:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: -25px auto 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25px;
    border-radius: 125px / 12px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.702);
}
```

Html code:
     `<div class="spacer"> <div class="mask"></div></div>`

Any idea why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: What version of Opera is 'older Opera'

Comment: 12.16, last version of old Opera

Comment: -o-box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="spacer"><div class="mask"></div></div>
```

css all browser

```
<style type="text/css">
    .spacer {
    width: 400px;
    position: relative;
}

.mask {
    margin-top: 5px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

 .mask:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    margin: -32px auto 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50% / 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px #202020;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px 6px gray;
}
</style>
```